# Java Jsoup parsing a site but not getting the needed elements

Tags: java, jsoup

[image]

https://goworkabit.com/tooampsud

How to parse this element's information?
I have tried this:

```
try {
    public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36";
    Connection connection; = Jsoup.connect("https://goworkabit.com/tooampsud").userAgent(USER_AGENT);
    Document doc; = connection.get();
    Elements jobs = doc.select("c-workbites-list__workbites-title");
    for (int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(jobs.get(i).text());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please improve the question: What information are you trying to extract specifically? What are you getting? What problems are you having specifically?

Comment: c-workbites-list__workbites-title
- "Mööbliteisaldaja / transporditööline" I want to retrieve this information, System.out.println(); prints nothing

Comment: Debugger shows that Elements jobs is empty.

Comment: It seems that you are running into a limitation of Jsoup: it parses the page's source, ignoring any changes to the DOM that occur via JavaScript. Looking at the page source, none of the HTML you want is present.

Comment: Do you know an alternative way?

Comment: Use different tool which supports JavaScript like Selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data in the table is loaded using javascript, when you just parse the page using Jsoup it will not contains any data from the table.
One options is to render the page using any page rendering tools like Selenium+web browser and then parse the page using Jsoup

You can attempt something like the following code. This should give you the required data to further parse. Please note this approach is quite slow as it expects a physical browser to load the data.

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try {
            driver.get("https://goworkabit.com/tooampsud");
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
            Elements jobs = doc.select("tr.c-workbites-table__workbites-row");
            for (Element job : jobs) {
                    System.out.print(job.select("td>a.c-workbites-table__workbites-title").text() +"    ,   ");
                    System.out.println(job.select("td.text-right").text());
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to parse the contents (System.out.println(doc); contains needed information), but debugging shows that Elements jobs is empty. But atleast there is some progress, also thanks for the snippet, I was not quite sure how to use the webdriver.

Comment: @KristjanKoemets, When I run the above code that I have pasted, I can see the data in the following format (approximately 274 lines!):                                                               Õhtune koristus Tähesaju värskelt avatud loomapoes , 13,75 € 5,00 €/h

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    try {
        driver.get("https://goworkabit.com/tooampsud");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
        Elements jobs = doc.select(".c-workbites-list__workbites-title");
        for (Element job : jobs) {
            if (!(job.toString()).contains("filled")) {
                System.out.println(job.text());
            }

        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

This worked for me, thanks Krishna!